# Query for Identical address, case-sensitive. Same record, different field

Tags: sql, string, case-sensitive

I need a select query that shows me identical address fields but is case sensitive.

Example:

```
smith road 1  **DOES NOT** match to Smith Road 1
```

But,

```
SMITH ROAD 1 **DOES** match to SMITH ROAD 1.
```

If anyone knows the answer could you please explain as simple as possible, as I would like to understand and not just "copy and paste".

Comment: SQL is usually case sensitive when comparing data. But you can use a case insensitive collation. Or do UPPER on both arguments.

Comment: With SQL questions, you should always tag the DBMS you are seeking the answer for. Or do you want a general answer here on all DBMS?

Comment: i wasn't able to tag dbms as i was "not allowed"/error message shown

Answer (score 1):

What you want:

```
SELECT * FROM T_AV_Adressen 
WHERE ADR_Name = 'Sears AG' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Case-insensitive:

```
WHERE ADR_Name = 'Sears Ag' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

You need collations to tell (Microsoft) SQL-Server how to compare two string values. 
Sorting in Czech for example works different from sorting in English.

By specifying CS/CI, you can also tell SQL server whether he should differentiate between capital/non-capital letters (case-sensitivity). Since equality is also a comparison, a collation can also appy to an equality comparison, not just to sorting.

To find duplicate entries AND differentiate between capital and non-capital letters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_AV_Adressen AS adr1 

INNER JOIN T_AV_Adressen AS adr2 
    ON adr2.ADR_Name = adr1.ADR_Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 
    AND adr2.ADR_UID <> adr1.ADR_UID
```

SQL-Server by default is case-insensitive, so you don't need to specify a CI collation. Also, SQL-Server ignores leading and trailing whitespaces, so `field1 = field2` is actually the same as `LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(field1))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(field2)))`

If you're using PostgreSQL, it will be case-sensitive by default.
So IF you're using PostGre, field1 = field2 would suffice, or LOWER(field1) = LOWER(field2) if you need case-insensitive. 
Another solution for Postgre to compare case-insensitive is field1::citext = field2::citext

Note that lower is more secure than UPPER, as some characters don't have an uppercase equivalent, e.g. the German double-s (ß)

Comment: So I guess a query in Access won't work at all? Thanks, @Stefan, will give it a try and cry if it doesn't work ;) x